# Error while deserializing the JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm getting the JSON output as follows:

```
{"data":
 [
   {
    "name":"followersQuery",
    "fql_result_set":[{"subscriber_count":300}]
    },
   {
   "name":"likesQuery",
   "fql_result_set":[{"like_count":0}]
   }
 ]
}
```

It is the output of multiple `fql` query.

I have created the following classes to deserialize the output:

```
public class ResultCount
    {
        [JsonProperty("subscriber_count")]
        public int Followers { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("like_count")]
        public int Likes { get; set; }
    }

    public class ResultItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fql_result_set")]
        public ResultCount ResultCounts { get; set; }
    }

    public class FacebookData
    {
        public List<ResultItem> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm getting error while de-serializing the output in the following line:

```
 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookData>(myOutput);
```

The error is:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)'
>   has some invalid arguments.

Not able to correct this. Can anyone please correct this?

Many many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ResultCounts` return type should be `List<Resultcount>`.

Change

```
public ResultCount ResultCounts { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<ResultCount> ResultCounts { get; set; }
```

---

On a sidenote you can get class structue by simply pasting your json here - [Json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/). It will automatically generate class structure for you. It can be use to validate your structure. Generated structure was like this:

```
public class FqlResultSet
{
    public int subscriber_count { get; set; }
    public int? like_count { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<FqlResultSet> fql_result_set { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Rohit Vats Thanks a bunch !